# ASP.NET MVC Web.config error with built in authentication when trying to browse a created REST service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, rest, web-config

It is not liking my web config at all. I need to make this change for my REST service so I do not get

IIS specified authentication schemes 'Basic, Anonymous', but the binding only supports specification of exactly one authentication scheme. Valid authentication schemes are Digest, Negotiate, NTLM, Basic, or Anonymous. Change the IIS settings so that only a single authentication scheme is used.

So the change I made is

```
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
        <authentication>
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
            <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
        </authentication>
    </security>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

And when I try to load the rest service it says

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

Any ideas?